# IoT Edge deployed into Kubernetes and managed with Azure Arc

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Working with a partner who want to use K8s across cloud and edge and potentially use Azure Arc to manage this. Azure IoT Edge will be deployed into K8s with the K8s cluster managed with Arc.
Has anyone done this? Any potential problems people see?
Thanks!

BTW - couldn't find a # for azure-arc and I don't have sufficient reputation points to create it. Gah.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy and manage `iotedged` via Arc however workload config still needs to be configured via IoT Hub. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/deploy-azure-iot-edge-workloads